Linear transformation of equation using inverse matrix method
I can't seem to understand why the following method works: 
Find the transformation equation of $y=4x-3$ after undergoing the transformation matrix
$$
T = \begin{bmatrix}
4 & 3 \\
1 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Approach:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 3 \\
1 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x' \\
y' \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
\end{bmatrix}
= T^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
x' \\
y' \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
\end{bmatrix}
= \frac{1}{7}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 \\
1 & -4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x' \\
y' \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
\end{bmatrix}
= \frac{1}{7}
\begin{bmatrix}
x'+3y' \\
x'-4y' \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\begin{gather*}
\begin{aligned}
x &= \frac{x' + 3y'}{7}, \\
y &= \frac{x' - 4y'}{7}.
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}
$$
Substituting in original equation $y=4x-3$ to obtain its equation after transformation:
$$
\frac{x' - 4y'}{7} = 4\left(\frac{x' + 3y'}{7}\right) - 3
$$
$$
16y'=21-3x'
$$
(1) Why does this work? Why  does the inverse of the transformation lead me to the correct equation after transformation? Doesn't the inverse "undo" the transformation, leading me to the original $x$ and $y$ values in terms of $x'$ and $y'$? 
(2) Also I've been told that the final equation can be rewritten in terms of $x$ and $y$ instead of $x'$ and $y'$ as it doesn't make a difference. Aren't they not the same terms? 

Thanks to anyone who can provide me with an explanation

The simplest way is to first represent $y=4x-3$ in its vector equation first.
We can write it as:
$$
\begin{align}
x &= x \\
y &= 4x-3 \\
\end{align}
$$
Equivalently, it can be written as:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
-3 \\
\end{bmatrix}+t
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
by letting $x=t$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$.
The vector equation of the transformation $T$ is given by:
$$
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hat{x} \\
\hat{y} \\
\end{bmatrix}
&=T
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
& =
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 3 \\
1 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
& =
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 3 \\
1 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
-3 \\
\end{bmatrix}+t
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
4 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\ 
\end{pmatrix} \\
& =
\begin{bmatrix}
-9 \\
3 \\
\end{bmatrix}+t
\begin{bmatrix}
16 \\
-3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
$$
for $t \in \mathbb{R}$.
The transformed cartesian equation can be written by splitting into its $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ components:
$$
\begin{align}
\hat{x} &= -9+16t \\
\hat{y} &= 3-3t \\
\end{align}
$$
By doing a simple substitution, the transformed cartesian equation is given by:
$$
\hat{y} = -\frac{3}{16}\hat{x} + \frac{29}{16}
$$
Hope it helps.
